# Problem with Sort by?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product

I am working with magento 1.7.0.2.
I have a problem with navigation layer. I moved the Sort by block from right to left and it work (Sort by Price) only when i have product in categories. When i don't have any product it doesn't work and the Sort by categories appears in right.

That is what i did :
 I changed in app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\catalog.xml

in Catalog Category (Anchor) i add this code :

```
<reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

and i edit this code :

```
<reference name="right">
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

To

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

What is my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have changed the

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>.
```

Try to convert this also

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>.
```

The issue may be by this ,i didn't test the code .

Comment: Thanks i resolve the problem. I do the same thing with Non-Anchor, but I just did a little error.